# Is there a way to reset the border, border-radius, and background-color CSS properties?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I am using Twitter bootstrap for the CSS of a page where I have  input. Bootstrap defines:
    border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
for select elements.

I want to reset (by overwriting in my own CSS) these Bootstrap CSS property. I tried: auto, inherit, none. But none work. I also tried the -moz prefix for the radius. No success.

I see that this doesn't work because in Firefox, a select that has NO border and NO border-style and NO background-color is rendered in a similar way with the webkit browsers.

You can check this by commenting out these rules in the Web Developer -> Inspect -> CSS view.

How can I do all this without touching the Bootstrap library?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no "reset" property in CSS. When you need that, you have to "reset" those properties in a way that you nullify those that you don't want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Bootstrap declarations have a higher [specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) than yours.

You can test this by adding `!important` after the declaration: `border: none !important`

Do not ship with this code, however. To fix it the right way, use another class or id to override Bootstrap's CSS.

Answer (score 10):

```
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0;
-o-border-radius: 0;
border-radius: 0;
border: 0;
```

That should reset the borders. As long as your preferred styles appear later than the ones provided by Bootstrap, they will take precedence. Also, -moz-appearance may help you override default Firefox appearances (or reset them).

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/-moz-appearance

Answer (score 3):

To reset properties, use value "initial", works on all properties:

```
-webkit-border-radius: initial;
-moz-border-radius: initial;
-o-border-radius: initial;
border-radius: initial;
border: initial;
```

Comment: This can be a comment. Answers should be more explainatory

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `!important` its not always a good solution but may be the reason you are experiencing problems, read more about when it might be good to user this method [here](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/).